# Returning a value from various loops within a function

Tags: swift, nested

I'm trying to return a realm object from a function that contains a serious of loops. The gist of the function is to create a randomly weighted generator using a switch statement to parse between various 'buckets' of lower and upper bound cumulative probabilities until a randomly generated double lands in one of these buckets, and thus returns the student object.

I originally was just changing a label when the correct student was selected, but I need to edit other parameters of the student outside of the function and thus I can't just return the name from the function anymore, but rather need to return the object. Old code is attached below. Only change I've made would be to add returned parameter to function name: func randomWeightedStudent() -> Student { ... } and instead of studentNameLabel.text = currentStudent.name I'd like to return currentStudent

```
func randomWeightedStudent() {

    let randomValue = Double.random(in: 0.00 ... 1.00)

    if let numberOfStudents = students?.count  {

        for i in 0 ... (numberOfStudents - 1) {

            guard let currentStudent = students?[i] else { continue }

            if i == 0 {

                switch randomValue {

                case (0 ... (currentStudent.prob)) :
                    studentNameLabel.text = currentStudent.name
                default :
                    break
                }

            } else if i < numberOfStudents {

                guard let lastStudent = students?[i-1] else { continue }

                switch randomValue {

                case (lastStudent.cumProb) ... (currentStudent.cumProb) :
                    studentNameLabel.text = currentStudent.name
                default :
                    break
                }

            } else if i == numberOfStudents {

                switch randomValue {

                case (currentStudent.cumProb) ... 1 :
                    studentNameLabel.text = currentStudent.name
                default :
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As described above, I'd like to be able to say return currentStudent in place of studentNameLabel.text = currentStudent.name but I'm not having success with that. Error is generating that function needs a return value which makes me speculate that I need to somehow return the value up a serious of each loop

Comment: What is the problem with letting your function return a Student object,  `-> Student`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - when I tried returning the student object and writing return (currentStudent) in the place of where the studentNameLabel.text = currentStudent.name, it still thinks I'm missing a return : Missing return in a function expected to return 'Student?'

Comment: You need to do it for every place you set the label and you also need a default value (nil?) to return when no condition is fulfilled. If you return nil then the function needs to return an optional value, ` -> String?`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've had all 3 instances of the label returning the Student object so that's not the problem. Also there is no instance in which the condition isn't fulfilled, but I did try and create an else as a catch-all and it didn't fix the warning. I don't understand how I could return a String? if my only return is Student?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part, I of course meant `-> Student?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would implement the function to return a Student object or nil. I also made some other simplifications to the code to make it clearer.

```
func randomWeightedStudent() -> Student? {
    let randomValue = Double.random(in: 0.00 ... 1.00)
    guard let students = students else { return nil }
    let numberOfStudents = students.count

    for i in 0..<numberOfStudents {
        let currentStudent = students[i]
        if i == 0 {
            switch randomValue {
            case (0 ... (currentStudent.prob)) :
            return currentStudent
            default :
                break
            }
        } else if i < numberOfStudents {
            let lastStudent = students[i-1]
            switch randomValue {
            case (lastStudent.cumProb) ... (currentStudent.cumProb) :
                return currentStudent
            default :
                break
            }
        } else if i == numberOfStudents {
            switch randomValue {
            case (currentStudent.cumProb) ... 1 :
                return currentStudent
            default :
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Fantastic - that worked, I was adding the return nil in the wrong place. Thanks a bunch!!